# How to enumerate the back-references of an entity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable, referenceproperty

In this scenario, company.py contains:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

class Company(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    address=db.StringProperty()

    def to_JSON():
        d = dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])
        return simplejson.dumps(d)
```

office.py contains:

```
from company import Company

class Office(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    company = db.ReferenceProperty(Company, collection_name='offices')
```

module 3 contains:

```
from company import Company

class Region(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    company = db.ReferenceProperty(Company, collection_name='regions')
```

This is a simplified example of what I need to do, but should capture it pretty well...  I need Company to be able to express itself as a JSON string, and it does not know about the other classes (Office and Region) that reference it.  This works for the normal properties:

```
c = Company(name='A Company',address='123 Main St, New York, NY 12345')
c.put()

dallas = Office(name='Dallas',company=c)
dallas.put()

ny = Office(name='New York',company=c)
ny.put()

northeast = Region(name='NorthEast',company=c)
northeast.put()

southwest = Region(name='SouthWest',company=c)
southwest.put()

logging.info('Company as JSON: %s' % c.to_JSON())
```

And what I get for output is:

```
{"name": "A Company", "address": "123 Main St, New York, NY 12345"}
```

So properties() includes the properties of the entity as expected, but I also want to include the back-references from the ReferenceProperty attributes of the associated objects.  Essentially what I'm looking for is just a list of the back-reference (collection_name) names, since I know they represent queries, but I can't find any way to enumerate the back-reference names themselves.

Remember this code isn't actually indicative of the real code, it's greatly simplified.  Now this works:

```
offices = getattr(company, 'offices')
```

So what I was expecting to see was this:

```
{"name": "A Company", "address": "123 Main St, New York, NY 12345", 
 "offices": "<db.Query object at 0x110e992d0>", 
 "regions": "<db.Query object at 0x110e99300>"
}
```

I don't actually *need* the back-references "offices" and "regions" to be included in the properties() enumerations, but they're checked for uniqueness somehow (I couldn't, for example, also have a StringProperty in Company named 'offices') so there must be a way to enumerate them.  Anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for uniqueness is simply against the class dict (that is, the internal object that provides a mapping between names and values for the class object). You can iterate over these by examining `Company.__dict__`. This includes everything, though - all the properties, attributes and methods of the built in Python `object`, likewise for `db.Model` and any other parent classes.

Your best option would be to iterate over the class dict, checking each item to see if it's an instance of `_ReverseReferenceProperty`:

```
for propname, prop in Company.__dict__.iteritems():
  if isinstance(prop, db._ReverseReferenceProperty):
    # Do something with prop, such as getting a query with getattr(a_company, propname).
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you don't assign values to `collection_name`, just leave it as `Modelname_set`. Then you can `dir(model)`, choose the attributes ending in `_set`, and those are the backreferences. Or you can make a convention to name them eg. `groups_refs`, and search for attributes ending in `_refs`.